# How to Group data into DropDownList using .net mvc and razor?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I want to categorize binding data from database inside of a dropdownlist. My database table has 4 colums: DepartmentId, Name, ParentID and Level. How can I group them according to level?

This is my code:

```
public ActionResult Departments()
{

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FormDatabaseEntities"].ToString()))
    {

        string sql = @"select * from tblDepartment  ORDER BY COALESCE(ParentID, DepartmentID)";
        var departments = connection.Query<tblDepartment>(sql).ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
        ViewBag.departments = list;
    }
    return View();
}
```

.cshtml side:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.ParentID, ViewBag.departments as SelectList, "Seçiniz...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: add code snippet that you have tried

Comment: yes i add below

Comment: Form Review: Please do not your question's code as an answer. Read this before using Stackoverflow: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This time I've edited your question for you and fixed this issue.

Comment: groupby clause, using linq

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I saw in your code snippet that you're using the `SelectList` class. It has a property `DataGroupField`. So all you have to do is

```
SelectList list = new SelectList(departments, "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName");
list.DataGroupField = "Level";
ViewBag.departments = list;
```

That should do the trick. The [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) has also some overloaded constructors that let you specify the group field.

*original post...*

If you're using items of type `SelectListItem` then you can utilize the `Group` property to assign a group to each item. This will automatically handle the grouping in your dropdown if you're using the `DropDownListFor` helper to generate the select list.

Check the documentation of the [SelectListItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) for more information.

Comment: could u show me sample code? i need recursive structure .User can add unlimited subdepartment.is it possible to list in dropdownlist if it is,how?i found combo tree js i want like this or with dropdown